# How to capture the output of SAP report RSPARAM into a table or a view?

Tags: eclipse

I am creating some CDS views and for that I need to call on some parameters from the RSPARAM report on SAP that is generated by executing the tcode SE32.
I do not have ABAP experience.
Can someone please tell me how I can capture the output of this report in a table or view?
Then it will be easier for me to refer to the values in this report from my CDS Views.

Comment: Tcode SE32 is used to create text elements for a report or class. RSPARAM report is used to display SAP profile parameters of the system. Not sure if there is any relation between those two. Can you please eloborate?